# Windows Integrated Authentication in node.js Client

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-authentication, node.js-client

When using node.js as a client, is it possible to connect to a server using Windows integrated authentication (e.g. when connecting to IIS)?

My searches for this only turn up results where node.js is used as a server.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**2015 Update:** There are now some modules that implement Windows-integrated authentication.  [node-sspi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi) uses SSPI (the Windows security API) to handle the server side of things, but [does not do client auth](https://github.com/abbr/NodeSSPI/issues/10).  There are [several client implementations](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=ntlm) such as [http-ntlm](https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm), but they are not truly integrated since they require the user password -- they do not use SSPI to do transparent auth.

**2019 Update:** It appears to be possible to use the [kerberos](https://github.com/mongodb-js/kerberos) library to do true Windows-integrated HTTP auth using SSPI (ie, use the node process' token to do transparent auth).  See [kerberos-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kerberos-agent). Obviously this uses Kerberos rather than NTLM/Negotiate, so this may or may not work depending on your exact situation.

---

"Windows integrated authentication" is what's known as NTLM authentication.  When you receive a HTTP 401 from IIS with a `WWW-Authenticate` header containing `NTLM`, you now have the fun of implementing the NTLM authentication protocol.  Quoting from [this document about the NTLM authentication protocol](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#ntlmHttpAuthentication):

---

1. The client requests a protected resource from the server:

   ```
   GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
   ```
2. The server responds with a `401` status, indicating that the client must authenticate. `NTLM` is presented as a supported authentication mechanism via the `WWW-Authenticate` header. Typically, the server closes the connection at this time:

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
   WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
   Connection: close
   ```

   Note that Internet Explorer will only select NTLM if it is the first mechanism offered; this is at odds with RFC 2616, which states that the client must select the strongest supported authentication scheme.
3. The client resubmits the request with an `Authorization` header containing a [Type 1 message](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#theType1Message) parameter. The Type 1 message is Base-64 encoded for transmission. From this point forward, the connection is kept open; closing the connection requires reauthentication of subsequent requests. This implies that the server and client must support persistent connections, via either the HTTP 1.0-style "Keep-Alive" header or HTTP 1.1 (in which persistent connections are employed by default). The relevant request headers appear as follows:

   ```
   GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
   Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAABzIAAAYABgArAAAACwALACAAAABXT1JLU1RBVElPTkRPTUFJTg==
   ```
4. The server replies with a `401` status containing a [Type 2 message](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#theType2Message) in the `WWW-Authenticate` header (again, Base-64 encoded). This is shown below.

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
   WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAADAAMADAAAAABAoEAASNFZ4mrze8AAAAAAAAAAGIAYgA8AAAARABPAE0AQQBJAE4AAgAMAEQATwBNAEEASQBOAAEADABTAEUAUgBWAEUAUgAEABQAZABvAG0AYQBpAG4ALgBjAG8AbQADACIAcwBlAHIAdgBlAHIALgBkAG8AbQBhAGkAbgAuAGMAbwBtAAAAAAA=
   ```
5. The client responds to the Type 2 message by resubmitting the request with an `Authorization` header containing a Base-64 encoded [Type 3 message](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#theType3Message):

   ```
   GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
   Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAGoAAAAYABgAggAAAAwADABAAAAACAAIAEwAAAAWABYAVAAAAAAAAACaAAAAAQIAAEQATwBNAEEASQBOAHUAcwBlAHIAVwBPAFIASwBTAFQAQQBUAEkATwBOAMM3zVy9RPyXgqZnr21CfG3mfCDC0+d8ViWpjBwx6BhHRmspst9GgPOZWPuMITqcxg==
   ```
6. Finally, the server validates the responses in the client's Type 3 message and allows access to the resource.

   ```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   ```

---

You'll have to figure out how you'll [reply to the Type 2 message's challenge](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#respondingToTheChallenge), where the user's password is MD4 hashed and used to create DES keys to encrypt the challenge data.

I'm not sure how you'd get access to the logged in user's credential data which would allow you to accomplish this, though I'm sure it would involve writing a [native C++ addon](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) so you could talk to the necessary Windows API.  Or, I suppose you could just ask for the user's password.

Alternatively, you could [proxy your Node requests through software that handles the NTLM mess for you](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: You can also see Negotiate, especially in a domain environment. In that case, a Kerberos ticket will be included in the `Authorization` header.

Comment: _Windows Integrated Authentication_ nowadays means Kerberos. NTLM is deprecated. Also the OP asked for the client side. The answer is therefore off topic.

Comment: @amadeus: He asked about using node *as* the client of IIS, which is exactly what this answers.  In regard to Kerberos vs NTLM, a `WWW-Authenticate` header of `Negotiate` means the server supports both (default in newer IIS).  You certainly could pursue implementing Kerberos -- there are [a couple modules on npm](https://npmjs.org/search?q=kerberos), but they're very poorly documented.

Comment: I found that the easiest way to do this from the client side is to use node-libcurl.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48015144/75129

Comment: In 2020, there is node-expose-sspi, which works well with Kerberos. Note: I am the author of node-expose-sspi.

Answer (score 4):

For Kerberos:

- node-sspi

  ```
  Just on windows
  No client side node
  Supports NTLM too
  ```
- passport-negotiate

  ```
  Needs python on the server
  it's a passportJs strategy
  ```

For NTLM

- node-sspi

  ```
  Just on windows
  No client side node
  Supports Kerberos too
  ```
- httpntlm
- express-ntlm
- request-ntlm
- ntlm

  ```
  experimental project!
  ```
- ntlm-auth

  ```
  experimental!
  ```
- passport-ntlm

  ```
  supports SMB protocol
  it's a passportJs strategy
  ```

I chose passport-negotiate for Kerberos and express-ntlm for NTLM

Comment: node-sspi doesn't work with Kerberos correctly per [Caveats](https://github.com/abbr/NodeSSPI#caveats)

Comment: node-expose-sspi works with both Kerberos and NTLM (Negotiate). Note: I am the author of node-expose-sspi.

Comment: Microsoft provides a number of SSPI packages. So far only NTLM and Negotiate have been tested working. Kerberos is not working. Contribution is encouraged. See caveats here https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi

Answer (score -1):

For client side, what works is to use node-libcurl to do REST / HTTP calls.

here's sample code:

```
var endpoint = urlString;
var url = require("url");
var endpointUrl = url.parse(endpoint);

var Curl = require( 'node-libcurl' ).Curl;
var curl = new Curl();

curl.setOpt( 'USERNAME', '' );
//curl.setOpt( 'VERBOSE', 1 );
curl.setOpt( 'URL', endpoint );
curl.setOpt( 'HTTPAUTH', Curl.auth.NEGOTIATE );
curl.setOpt( 'NOPROXY', endpointUrl.hostname );

curl.on( 'end', function( statusCode, body, headers ) {

    if (statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body);
        cb(null, { statusCode, body, headers } ); 
    } else {
        cb(new Error(), { statusCode, body, headers } ); 
    }

    this.close();
});

curl.on( 'error', curl.close.bind( curl ) );
curl.perform();
```