# Running NodeJS on IIS7.5 to use Window Authentication SSO

Tags: node.js, iis, active-directory, single-sign-on

We are running a nodeJS web app on IIS7.5 with the help of IIS node.

What we want to achieve is that the user will only have to login to his company user on the PC without re-entering the Username and Password to access the web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment above solved the problem indeed.
Browsing to the web site without periods on the address solves the problem.

> If you add periods to your URL when you are browsing it will automatically prompt the login window. for example: 10.0.0.1/myapp - will prompt login info myappdnsadress/myapp - will not prompt a window source:

http://support.Microsoft.com/en-us/kb/258063

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949163/windows-integrated-authentication-in-node-js-client), it describes the usage of: node-sspi - uses Windows security API.

Comment: I rememeber that I tried it but i'm not sure if it didin't work becaouse of the need thing that I found out:  
If you add periods to your URL when you are browsing it will automatically prompt the login window. for example:  
10.0.0.1/myapp - will prompt login info
myappdnsadress/myapp - will not prompt a window

source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/258063

I'll update if it worked :)