# How to use DefaultCredentials in TypeScript HTTP request

Tags: node.js, typescript

Need help to find analogous of this powershell construct in Typescript:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://internalurl"  -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials
```

I tried the following request in typescript:

```
        const options = {
            url: `${this.endpoint}/API/${url}`,
            withCredentials: true
        };

        const response = await request(options);
        return JSON.parse(response);
```

Not sure how do I specify the request to use Default credentials.

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949163/windows-integrated-authentication-in-node-js-client/13960538#13960538

Comment: Maybe this package can help you? https://www.npmjs.com/package/keytar

Comment: What is your run-time environment?, are you running in browser or NodeJS? In worst case scenario you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-powershell

Comment: I am currently using node-powershell. Running in NodeJS.