# XMLHttpRequest File Upload with NTLM - File is being uploaded twice

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

I am currently working on a web application that involves async file upload using a XMLHttpRequest.

When using NTLM authentication (which is a bit of a necessity), the async POST ends up being sent twice. The first time the response is a 401, and the second time it is a 200. This is sort of what I expected due to the challenge/response nature of NTLM, but I was wondering whether there is a way to avoid sending the file data both times (especially since the file being uploaded could be quite large), maybe by somehow sending an empty request first to trigger the 401 before sending the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a browser, there's not much you can do to avoid this situation due to the nature of HTTP and the NTLM authentication protocol.

However, I don't think the entire file's data is actually getting sent twice.

I sent the following to a NTLM-protected file on IIS 7.5:

```
POST /test/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 5
```

Notice that I didn't actually send any content, only complete headers.  However, IIS **immediately** responded:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
Date: Thu, 10 Jan 2013 05:17:58 GMT
Content-Length: 6277

...
```

This means that if I was a browser uploading a large file, I'd be cut off well before I transferred very many bytes.  I'd assume (hope) that any well-behaved browser would give up the file upload and begin the HTTP authentication.

It may be worth your time to get out something like Wireshark to see what's actually going over the wire.  (Remember to test with different browsers!)  Don't trust in-browser developer tools, and don't use debugging proxies like Fiddler.  (In fact, if you're using Fiddler, that might actually be the problem: it buffers the *entire* request before sending *anything* to the server.)

If you do find that the entire file is indeed getting uploaded in its entirety twice (maybe older versions of IIS doesn't send the immediate `401`?), consider how things must happen:

1. The user submits an upload, causing the browser to issue a `POST` request to the server.  Because the browser cannot possibly know if the URL requires authentication, it just sends the *complete* request off.

   ```
   POST /upload HTTP/1.1
   Content-Type: mutlipart/form-data
   Content-Length: 1024

   ...
   ```
2. The server might respond immediately with a `401`, but a poorly behaved user agent goes about transmitting the entire request anyway.
3. Once the request completes and the browser sees the `401`, we begin the [NTLM dance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5452258/201952).  The client must issue a new request with a [Type 1](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#theType1Message) message, The server responds with another `401`, this time containing a Type 2 message, and finally the client issues a *third* request with a Type 3 message containing the actual credentials.

   Since a client knows that the second request is guaranteed to be another `401` in NTLM negotiation, it knows it can skip the transmission of the entity (the form data).  However, it must send the post data for a second time on the third request, since we must assume that the server discarded the original request data.
4. Our file is finally uploaded!  (But it had to be transmitted twice.)

So while I don't think you'll actually see a *complete* double-uploading problem with NTLM authentication, you might still want to eliminate the possibility.  Here's how I'd tackle it:

Move the upload URL **outside** of the NTLM authenticated area.  On the upload page (which is NTLM authenticated), either use a session cookie (set when loading the page) or issue a token – a GUID in a hidden field should suffice.

The script receives uploads can reject any request that does not have a valid session and/or token.

If you're using the NTLM credentials as a mechanism to grant access to NTFS resources, the upload could be written to an anonymously-writable temporary folder, and when done, redirect the request to a second NTLM-protected script which moves the file to its destination.

Comment: You might be right that it is some sort of UserAgent specific issue. The file upload itself is being done by a third-party JS plugin by constructing an XMLHttpRequest and uploading the file. The thing that triggered this discussion was the fact that you could see the progress bar go round twice at the same speed. I shall have a look with Wireshark and see what comes up.

Comment: Having dug deeper with Wireshark, it appears to be an issue with Chrome. If the URL you are accessing is a trusted site, it uses GSS-API to send both Kerberos and NTLM authentication details. Kerberos is given a higher priority so IIS decides to use that instead. It was the Kerberos authentication that was happening for every request , so by disabling Kerberos on IIS, authentication was done using NTLM, which is connection based, so the 401 only happened on the first request. =)

Comment: Ah, perfect.  This is something I didn't mention in my post -- with NTLM authentication, IIS will send a (proprietary?) [`Persistent-Auth: true`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd341152.aspx) header once the client successfully authenticates.  This indicates that the client need not re-send `Authorization` headers for subsequent requests *over the same TCP connection*.

Comment: Also, [there's a setting that enables `Persistent-Auth` for Kerberos](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2011/10/31/kerberos-authpersistnonntlm-authentication-request-based-vs-session-based-authentication.aspx), should you find you actually need it.  (Kerberos is more secure than NTLM, so it might be worth looking in to.)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is unlikely that the customers using this software will have Kerberos set up properly so we need to support NTLM at least for now, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your implementation but it looks like others have experienced similar issues with cURL and NTLM. Based on the links below, there's a possibility your idea of making any empty request first might work.

POST file twice over NTLM-proxy
http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2007-01/0040.html

> > I'm using curl_formadd and POST-method to send file via proxy with 
> >     NTLM-auth. Looking on ProgressFunction, I see that my file send twice 
> >     (probably because of NTLM-specific). Am I right or not?
>
> You are right. There's no way to avoid that when using NTLM, since we
>   can't  abort the transfer once it has started.

Different behaviour of file upload with NTLM/Negotiate proxy authentication
http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2012-11/0013.html